# How can I count items inside an array with reduce?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, items: [...some data]},
  { id: 2, items: [...some data]},
  { id: 3, items: [...some data]},
]
```

I'm counting the total `items` for each object inside the array.

I'm currently counting with:

```
let total = 0;
  myArray.forEach((obj) => {
    total += obj.items?.length;
  });
```

How could I do the same but with `reduce`? or any shorter way without that `let total`

Comment: How about you give a try and then ask the question again showing what you came up with including actual vs. expected behavior? Otherwise, we're just writing out s solution for you instead of helping you figure out which part you're not understanding.

Comment: Also be careful that `obj.items?.length` may return undefined and undefined will return NaN when added to a number

Comment: @tekyu there are a million examples out there. I'd rather help understanding what is the difficulty instead of just offering a snippet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#sum_of_values_in_an_object_array

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
myArray.reduce( (total, {items} ) => total + items.length, 0)
```

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times; there's no need for another answer. Also, answers which have no explanation are generally downvoted more often than those with some explanation.

Comment: @StudioTime and yet I provided an answer to his question. What did you do?

Comment: I was able to find a link in pretty short order... The OP gets their answer, with explanation, and more importantly, later searchers don't have to go through 1467 different questions and answers to find their answer. Oh, and I never said it's a bad question.

Comment: @Tekyu, code only answers are not that helpful. A link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#sum_of_values_in_an_object_array is probably better

Comment: Also note that your example may be broken if any of the arrays are null, considering the OP used obj.items?.length

Comment: Actually you did not answer the OP question... well, not entirely, at least. Looking at the code, it looks like `items` might not have a length property (maybe because it can be `null` or `undefined`) and your proposed solution does not take that into account.

Comment: For the data OP had shown, the items would always be an array, thus it would have length property. No need to overly verbose/specific code tackling every single corner case.

Comment: The OP also mentioned the aim was to replace `forEach((obj) => { total += obj.items?.length; });` with a `reduce()`. The need for that check is a direct consequence of the OP request, not an "overly verbose corner case", IMVHO.